# Getting connection timeout while reading file from s3 using aws sdk 2x

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, spring-batch, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I have a batch application which reads large file from amazon s3. MyS3 config:

```html
@Configuration
    public class S3Configuration {
        @Bean
        public S3Client s3Client() {
            return S3Client.builder()
                    .credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.create())
                    .region(Region.AP_EAST_1)
                    .overrideConfiguration(ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder().apiCallAttemptTimeout(Duration.ofHours(6)).build())
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

And for reading the file

```html
GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName).key(key)
                .build();

ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> getObjectResponseResponseInputStream = s3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest);
```

But I'm getting connection time out error about after half an hour.
Attaching stack trace

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:323) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:484) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readFully(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:467) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:243) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:181) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1509) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1480) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1065) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137) ~[httpcore-4.4.16.jar:4.4.16]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.read(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:197) ~[httpcore-4.4.16.jar:4.4.16]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:176) ~[httpcore-4.4.16.jar:4.4.16]
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132) ~[na:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.checksums.ChecksumValidatingInputStream.read(ChecksumValidatingInputStream.java:112) ~[s3-2.20.144.jar:na]
at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132) ~[na:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.io.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:66) ~[sdk-core-2.20.144.jar:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:270) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:313) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:188) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:177) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:162) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:329) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:396) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.readLine(FlatFileItemReader.java:216) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
```

I have tried with apiCallAttemptTimeout, apiCallTimeout, retryPolicy etc. But nothing works out for me. Can someone please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Where you have deployed your application? It is lambda or ecs ?

Comment: Try using S3 Transfer Manager API. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/transfer-manager.html

Comment: ALso -- how large is the object you are using?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal It's in ecs

Comment: @smac2020 file size is around 6 GB

Comment: @smac2020 I don't want to use the transfer manager as I don't want to download the file. I just want to read the file at runtime.

Comment: What does your item writer do?

Comment: @httPants It's saving the data to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout issue would be caused by the delay caused by your ItemWriter updating a database after each batch of lines is read from your file.  To work around this you could either

a) Implement an ItemReader that used byte range fetches to read the s3 file in chunks (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/s3-optimizing-performance-best-practices/use-byte-range-fetches.html); or

b) Download the file to a local temporary file in a step (via a tasklet), then read that local temporary file in the chunk oriented step that updates the database.